# How to translate simplejwt error (django rest framework)?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, internationalization, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

What is the best way to translate the error:
"No active account found with the given credentials" coming from:

```
from rest_framework_simplejwt.views import TokenObtainPairView
...
urlpatterns = [
    path('token/', TokenObtainPairView.as_view()),
```

I use React on the frontend and Django and Django Rest Framework on the backend.
I changed django settings to:
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'pl'
but this apparently didn't change the simplejwt error language.

Comment: Hqve you added `rest_framework_simplejwt` to the installed apps in your settings?

Comment: @Marco Yes, that's it. Thank you. Although rest_framework_simplejwt seemed to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*In case others also have this question, here is the answer:*

Add `rest_framework_simplejwt` to the installed apps as described in the [Simple JWT documentation](https://django-rest-framework-simplejwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html):

> If you wish to use localizations/translations, simply add `rest_framework_simplejwt` to `INSTALLED_APPS`.